# Bulk Password Hashing PHP-LOGIN PROJECT code

Tags: php, mysql, hash, php-password-hash

I have the following question / requirement.

My website has 2000 users, however the passwords are stored using Plain text (I know this is super bad). From reading various website blogs, i found that i need to use modern password-hashing and salting. I found [php-login.net](http://www.php-login.net/) . They use modern salting / hashing.

I have downloaded the minimal login script which i will implement in my website. I have set up xampp to test locally. When i register a user is hashes the passwords and i can login.

My main requirement is that i want to hash all my current plain text passwords. php login using php password compatibility library.

[password_compatibility_library](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal/blob/master/libraries/password_compatibility_library.php)

How can i hash all the plain passwords in database, because i am not going to hash 2000 1 by 1.

I assume i can write  a script that will update all records in database using the password library.

Comment: _I assume i can write a script that will update all records in database using the password library._ Seems that you answer your own question. Script it ;)

Comment: I don't know where to begin with this.  I need some guidance on how i can achieve this.

Comment: Use bcrypt without an extra salt column. Best way of storing passwords nowadays. Anyway: just getting all the current users, fetch their password, encrypt it and store it back. I don't see what the problem can be here? It would be a simple PHP script with approx. 5 lines of code.

Comment: I recommend to add one salt column, add one salt per record & then write a script to read salt per record -> apply you encoding algo per rec-> save it back to db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
// you should put your db connection stuff here
require('connect.php'); 

//you create a new column to store hashed passwords. Good idea if
//something goes bad. You should drop the column with the original
// passwords once every thing is ok and done.
$result = mysqli_query(
    $conn,
    'alter table users add column hashed_password varchar(255) not null'
); 

if ($result===FALSE)
{
// handle error here
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'select * from users');
if ($result===FALSE)
{
// handle error here
}else
{
    while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
    {
        // you could use PASSWORD_DEFAULT here but I wouldn't. If in a
        // future migration the default password crypt function changes
        // your system won't work and it will be hard to know why.
        $hashedPassword = password_hash($user['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,'update users set hashed_password = \''. mysqli_real_escape_string($hashedPassword) .'\' where id=\''. $user['id'] .'\'');
        if ($result2 === FALSE)
        {
        //handle error here
        }
    }
}
```

then you simply check the password in `hashed_password` column and not the original. If everything goes ok and you can login with no issues you can delete the original passwords column and you are done.

Comment: Your code worked well thanks!. i also added a button to be pressed for the query to run. :)

Comment: I'd recommend param binding rather than `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, but otherwise good stuff!

Comment: Thank you. Switching to OO + prepared statements, but not yet got the hang of it. Plus as most people are still at mysql_* and not mysqli i thought this would be easier to follow ...

Comment: shouldn't use VARCHAR for a fixed-length hash though

Answer (score 2):

PHP now has a [hash_password()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function that uses BCrypt.

This should be easy to script in a couple of lines.

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $hashed = password_hash($user->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    echo "Hashed user {$user->id}\n";
    // Do db query here
}
```

Take a look at [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) too!